# Make slider bubble keep up with the left handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, uislider

I have a collection of items I wish to filter by some criteria (rating, but it could be anything else). For this, I have a jQuery UI slider:

```js
$("#rating_slider").slider({
  range: true,
  step: 0.5,
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  values: [3, 10],
  animate: "slow",
  orientation: "horizontal",
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#amount").text(ui.value);
  }
});
```

```css
.toolbar {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#slider-container {
  position: relative;
}

#rating_slider {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

#amount {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -27px;
  display: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

#rating_slider:active #amount {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="toolbar rounded-sm clearfix">
  <div class="d-inline-block pl-4" id="slider-container">
    <p class="my-0 pr-3 d-inline-block">Filter by rating:</p>
    <div id="rating_slider" class="d-inline-block">
      <div id="amount">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I have a "bubble" that displays the *current value* of the UI slider. The bubble has `position: absolute;` and `bottom: -27px;` so it is properly placed vertically (on the Oy axis).

But its `left` position should be **dynamic**, so that the bubble would keep up with the (left) handle.

I have not been able to achieve that.

What is the simplest, most "robust" way to achieve it?

UPDATE:

I have captured the `style` attribute of the handle, which **should be useful** but I **can not set it** on the `#amount element`:

```
$("#rating_slider").slider({
  range: true,
  step: 0.5,
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  values: [3, 10],
  animate: "slow",
  orientation: "horizontal",
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var bubblex = $(this).find('.ui-state-focus').attr('style');
    console.log(bubblex);
    $(this).find("#amount").css({
      "left": bubblex
    });
  }
});
```

How can I set it to `#amount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are having trouble converting the percentage value to pixel, I would rather move the `#amount` element to someplace else to get a better positioning of itself.

Let's try moving it inside of those `.ui-state-focus` anchors while the slide starts.

```js
$("#rating_slider").slider({
  range: true,
  step: 0.5,
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  values: [3, 10],
  animate: "slow",
  orientation: "horizontal",
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    //$("#amount").text(ui.value);
    $(this).find('.ui-state-focus').append($(this).find('#amount').text(ui.value)); //move the amount inside of an active anchor and update it's text value; 
  }
});
```

```css
.toolbar {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#slider-container {
  position: relative;
}

#rating_slider {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

#amount {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -27px;
  display: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%; /* as it's translated to -50%; put a left value of 50% to center align; */
}

#rating_slider:active #amount {
  display: inline-block;
  /*margin-left: 20px;*/ /* remove the margin */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="toolbar rounded-sm clearfix">
  <div class="d-inline-block pl-4" id="slider-container">
    <p class="my-0 pr-3 d-inline-block">Filter by rating:</p>
    <div id="rating_slider" class="d-inline-block">
      <div id="amount">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the slider's value to set the `left` positioning relative to the element. The basic idea is to convert the value into some % of the width of the slider.

```
$("#rating_slider").slider({
  range: true,
  step: 0.5,
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  values: [3, 10],
  animate: "slow",
  orientation: "horizontal",
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#amount").text(ui.value);

    //Set the 'left' position dynamically
    $("#amount").css(
      "left", `${ ui.value*10 + "%" }`
    );
});
```

OR as per your edit

```
$("#rating_slider").slider({
  range: true,
  step: 0.5,
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  values: [3, 10],
  animate: "slow",
  orientation: "horizontal",
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var bubblex = $(this).find('.ui-state-focus').css('left');
    console.log(bubblex);
    $(this).find("#amount").css(
      "left", bubblex
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? It's working as you want.

Comment: Yes, but is has some issues.

Comment: Can you expound on the issue?

Comment: This does not work: `$(this).find("#amount").css({
      "left": bubblex
    });`.

Comment: Still not working. I guess the `#amount` is not selected, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version with the indicator showing only if the handle is used (moved), with some more visual improvements. I hope it helps more developers.

```js
$("#rating_slider").slider({
  range: true,
  step: 0.5,
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  values: [3, 10],
  animate: "slow",
  orientation: "horizontal",
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).find('.ui-state-focus').append($(this).find('#amount').show().text(ui.value));
  }
});
```

```css
.toolbar {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
}

#slider-container {
  position: relative;
}

#rating_slider {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

#amount {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -24px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: none;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

#amount:after,
#amount:before {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  right: auto;
}

#amount:before {
  top: -5px;
  left: 14px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e2e2e2;
}

#amount:after {
  top: -4px;
  left: 14px;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff;
}

.ui-state-focus,
#amount {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="toolbar rounded-sm clearfix">
  <div class="d-inline-block pl-4" id="slider-container">
    <p class="my-0 pr-3 d-inline-block">Filter by rating:</p>
    <div id="rating_slider" class="d-inline-block">
      <div id="amount">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```